# How do I show a map legend on an Android Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps

The web version of Google maps allows the developer to show a map legend that indicates the map's scale.

Is there any way to do this using the Android API?

Additional info:

- I want to show a graphical "this distance is equal to X meters" kind of display like you get if you go to a google map.
- It should be possible to use: getProjection() but I was just hoping there was a way to just enable the legend.
- If you open the Google Maps app and select "Labs" you can enable the "Scale bar" that's what I want.

Comment: I think you are going to have to use getProjection as you say. Find GeoPoints on left and right side of screen, work out km between them, pick suitable 1km/10km (depending on zoom) etc line to draw and draw it on a canvas with some text and add it as an overlay. Maybe add some subdivision tick marks. Pretty tedious but it should look good when you've done it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at how they did for the very similar Osmdroid which is for OpenStreetMap

[ScaleBarOverlay](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/ScaleBarOverlay.java?r=1087)

it should give some ideas. It's probably more fully featured than you need.

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout with the text view, load it in your onCreate and then write the map scale into it using setText(). An example layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/root">
        <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:enabled="true"
                                 android:clickable="true"
                                 android:id="@+id/map"
                 android:apiKey="<YOUR KEY>"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentL
eft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
                <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginLeft="10sp" android:layout_marginRight="10sp" android:layout_marginTop="10sp" android:id="@+id/scale" android:gravity="center_horizontal"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your activity, you can do

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.scale)).setText("<map scale>");
```

and it should appear on top of the map. You can style the text view however you want as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. See questions for additional info